# How to toggle ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In this ng-repeat I am going to display the first 2 row. while I am clicking show more how can I change the css **display:block**. Show More should to be toggle.

JSON

```
"one":[{  
       "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake"
    }]
"two":[{  
       "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake"
    }]
"three":[{  
       "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake"
    }]
"four":[{  
       "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake"
    }]
"five":[{  
       "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake"
    }]
```

HTML

```
    <div class="GridBrd" ng-repeat="Detail in Results" 
     ng-class='{showflight: $index > 1}'>  </div>

    <span class="moreOpt" ng-click="show()" 
       <a href="javascript:void(0);">Show More</a>
    </span>
```

css

```
.showflight{
    display:none;
 }
```

Script

```
 $scope.show = function (){
    ***----how can I change the ng-class block and none here?----***
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative answer perhaps you could use `limitTo` built-in filter on your `ngRepeat`. The idea is that you have a button to toggle the expression and the limitTo will switch to the max length of the items when `showAll` is true and will fallback on `2` when false;

e.g.

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.showAll = !$ctrl.showAll">Toggle</button>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items | limitTo: ( $ctrl.showAll ? $ctrl.items.length : 2 )">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/graemegeorge/pen/59c118d63a8a45111af723be471c0f9d)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-class="{ 'displayBlock' : variable,  'displayNone' : !variable }">
   ...
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.displayBlock {
    display: block;
}
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}
```

and in *controller.js*:

```
$scope.variable = false;
if(your condition) {
   $scope.variable = true;
}
```

That's how you can change css class in angular.
Maybe it's overkill, but I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="GridBrd" ng-repeat="Detail in Results" 
 ng-class='{showflight: $index > 1 && !showAll}'>  </div>

<span class="moreOpt" ng-click="showAll = !showAll">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);">Show More</a>
</span>
```